# Rendering views from xslt in MVC2

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-2, xslt

Years ago (.net 2005, C#)  I used to make an AJAX call via javascript to an HTTPHandler (controller), and have it call it call business objects that returned XML (model).  This XML was parsed through a generic routine using an XSLT (view) then returned as HTML using the Response.Write method where it was dynamically rendered on the master page using Javascript.

Using MVC2 I see how the controller and the model are the same but I can't see how to use an Xslt file as the view and have a generic transformation process render my html in a clean fashion without the overhead of using an aspx/ascx with System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.Xml object.  This seems neither generic nor lightweight.  Is there a way to do this?  Ideally I would love to write a generic View method where I would pass the view name and the xml and get the two merged via 1 single transformation pipeline.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have a custom view rendering engine registered to do the same.. You could use the following links as reference:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/partial-renderi.html
and 
http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Creating_a_Custom_View_Engine_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx

Also there is an open source project out there that does the same for you.. here is the link

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=XSLT

Also I want to add functional language style like XSLT makes flow control difficult..